# Avoid df.iterrow to drop dataframe rows within certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

colA = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
colB = [(21,1,2), (0,1,21), (2,1,21), (1,12,5), (21,1,0), (12,5,6), (18,7,14), (7,5,12), (14,7,18), (12,7,11), (11,7,12), (3,5,7)]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(colA, colB)), columns = ['colA', 'colB'])
display(df)
```

output:

```
    colA    colB
0   a   (21, 1, 2)
1   a   (0, 1, 21)
2   a   (2, 1, 21)
3   a   (1, 12, 5)
4   b   (21, 1, 0)
5   b   (12, 5, 6)
6   b   (18, 7, 14)
7   b   (7, 5, 12)
8   c   (14, 7, 18)
9   c   (12, 7, 11)
10  c   (11, 7, 12)
11  c   (3, 5, 7)
```

I'd need to drop (or filter out) all the rows where, *within the same value* of `colA`, a value of `colB` in a row is equal to the reverse value of `colB` in another row.
In the example provided:

- within `colA='a'` row 2 has `colB=(2,1,21)` which is the reverse of row 0 `colB=(21,1,2)` and thus should be dropped
- `colA='b'` row 4 has `colB=(21,1,0)` which is the reverse of row 1 `colB=(0,1,21)` but that's `colA='a'` so nothing to drop here
- within `colA='c'` row 10 has `colB=(11,7,12)` which is the reverse of row 9 `colB=(12,7,11)` and thus should be dropped

Final results would something like:

```
    colA    colB
0   a   (21, 1, 2)
1   a   (0, 1, 21)
2   a   (1, 12, 5)
3   b   (21, 1, 0)
4   b   (12, 5, 6)
5   b   (18, 7, 14)
6   b   (7, 5, 12)
7   c   (14, 7, 18)
8   c   (12, 7, 11)
9   c   (3, 5, 7)
```

Observations:

1. Preferable to drop row on a duplicated dataframe and keep the original
2. Very important: my real dataframe has shape (3millions, 11), so I am looking for an efficient way to do this, like .apply, lambda etc..I did this in the past with df.iterrows, it was already not the best way, my bad..now it's completely unfeasible

Current df.iterrows solution:

```
unique_df = df.copy()
seen_a_b = set()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    val_a = row['colA']
    val_b = row['colB']
    a_b = (val_a, val_b)
    a_revb = (val_a, val_b[::-1])
    if a_b in seen_a_b:
        unique_df.drop(i, inplace=True)
        continue
    seen_a_b.add(a_b)
    seen_a_b.add(a_revb)
```

Comment: What about rows where `colB` is the same? E.g. say you have a row `a   (21, 1, 2)` followed by a second row with the same content. Should that be dropped too? Do you care how that's handed?

Comment: Hi @NickODell, thanks for replying. In principle in my real df this situation does not happen if both rows are `colA='a'`, whereas it can happen to have two same `colB` value if in one row `colA` is `a` and in the other is `b`. In that case shouldn't be dropped

Comment: Can you include your current iterrows() solution, even if it's unfeasible? It's useful to have a reference implementation to compare to.

Comment: @NickODell df.iterrows solution now appended to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['colA',df['colB'].map(lambda x: frozenset((x[0],x[-1])))],as_index=False).first()
```

This solution creates a frozenset, or an immutable set that can be used as a groupby key. This, along with colA is used to get the first value of each group. We are only using the first and last value in colB, as the middle value is the same forward and backwards.

or

```
df.loc[df['colB'].map(lambda x: frozenset((x[0],x[-1]))).groupby(df['colA']).transform(lambda x: ~x.duplicated())]
```

or

```
df.loc[~pd.concat([df['colA'],df['colB'].map(lambda x: frozenset([x[0],x[-1]]))],axis=1).duplicated()].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  colA         colB
0    a   (21, 1, 2)
1    a   (0, 1, 21)
2    a   (1, 12, 5)
3    b   (21, 1, 0)
4    b   (12, 5, 6)
5    b  (18, 7, 14)
6    b   (7, 5, 12)
7    c  (14, 7, 18)
8    c  (12, 7, 11)
9    c    (3, 5, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks @rhug123 this is working! Could you please share more information about what your nice code is doing? I believe it will be helpful also for all the people who will see your proposed solution :)

Comment: okay i added a brief explanation. If this helped, please mark it as the accepted answer to close out the question!